# Java Apache Httpclient and ImageIO read captcha from URL

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, javax.imageio

I am writing a program to do the following job:

1. read a captcha from URL which the captcha image will change every time. 
   e.g. domain/captcha.do 
   It will return an image with 3 letters displays
2. my program will wait for input the 3 letters and then submit to do checking. 
   e.g. the captcha value is "QWE", user input "QWE" and my program will build the URL string: domain/doesitpass.do?capvalue=QWE and proceed the get/post.
3. In Chrome/Firefox, I open a tab and then go to domain/captcha.do first, it returns 3 letters (e.g. ZXC), then I open a new tab and then paste as domain/doesitpass.do?capvalue=ZXC, it will return a json {"error":"0","passcode":"blablablaXXX"}
4. However, in the eclipse development tool, I call the captcha.do first, save the image to a temporary folder, then type the 3 letters by observe the image letters (e.g. ZXC) to the input console, submit to domain/doesitpass.do?capvalue=ZXC will returns {"error":"1"} which means incorrect passcode.

My question is, why in browser view, Step 3 can get the correct message while in 4, it cannot? And how I can make my program to pass the checking? Thanks.

Part of my codes is as follows:

```
Scanner sd=new Scanner(System.in); 

imgStr = "domain/captcha.do" 

URL url=new URL(imgStr); 
BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(url); 
ByteArrayOutputStream osByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ImageIO.write(img1, "jpg", new File("C://image//test.jpg")); 

imageValue = sd.nextLine(); 

passcodeURL = "domain/doesitpass.do?capvalue=" + imageValue 

// or httpPost, both try, same result 
httpGet = new HttpGet(passcodeURL); 
response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

Sorry for my poor English. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the headers (especially cookies) sent by Chrome/Firefox. The capctha validator needs some way to figure out what challenge you are responding to. The easiest way is probably to enable cookies in the HTTP client, and download the captcha image using the same client that posts the response back. Bonus tip: There's no need to involve `ImageIO` here unless you actually want to display or modify the image data. Just write the bytes from the URL directly to disk.

Comment: @haraldK : thanks, I am thinking of using the Cookie too. Do you have any sample? Thanks.

Comment: What did you find in the headers? And, why not just try, and post an update with your findings? I don't have a computer nearby, but I can't imagine it should be that hard to enable cookies in Apache HttpClient.